# How to Check Answer in a Quiz when the Button isSelected

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and Coding. My english is not so good so apologize in advance!
I want to build a Quiz App. Now I have some trouble with checking the correct Answer because my uibuttons can be selected. The Reason for that ist that I would like to have multiple Answers with multiple Choice and multiple correct answers.

I don't know what kind of Informationen of my Code do you need from me but I will post what I mean it could help.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!!!

Class

```
import Foundation

class Quiz {
    
    let question: String
    let options : [String]
    let correctAnswer: [String]
    
    init(question: String, options: [String], correctAnswer: [String]) {
        self.question = question
        self.options = options
        self.correctAnswer = correctAnswer
    }
    
    func validateOption(_ index: Int) -> Bool {
        
        let answer = options[index]
        return answer == correctAnswer[index]
        
    }
    
    deinit {
        
    }
    }
```

My Viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var quenstionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var answerButton: [UIButton]!
    
    let quizManager = QuizManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getNewQuiz()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func checkAnswerButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
   
    
    @IBAction func checkMarkAnswerClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        if sender.isSelected {
            sender.isSelected = false
            
        } else {
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }
```

and my Quiz Manager

```
import Foundation

class QuizManager {
    
    private var quiz: Quiz!
    private var _totalAnswers = 0
    private var _totalCorrectAnswers = 0
    
    var question: String {
        return quiz.question
    }
    
    var options: [String] {
        return quiz.options
    }
    
    var totalAnswers: Int {
        return _totalAnswers
    }
    var totalCorrectAnswers: Int {
        return _totalCorrectAnswers
    }
    
    func refreshQuiz(){
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quizes.count)))
        let quizData = quizes[randomIndex]
        quiz = Quiz(question: quizData.question, options: quizData.options, correctAnswer: quizData.correctAnswer)
    }
    
    func validateAnswer(index: Int){
        _totalAnswers += 1
        if quiz.validateOption(index){
            _totalCorrectAnswers += 1
        }
    }
```

If there are needed more Informations, please let me know!!

It would be great, if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem following these steps.

1. Add an array for your answers in Question Class.
2. Second Add Delegate in your cell class that will notify your view controller
3. implement that delegate in view controller and append answers to your model.
4. On check button tapped simply compare array of your tapped answers with correct answers array.

//Step 1
var myAnswers:[String]

```
 protocol CheckAnswerDelegate : class {
     func didPressOptionButton(myAnswer: String)
 }

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            checkAnswerDelegate?.didPressOptionButton(myAnswer: self.answerButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "")
        }

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CheckAnswerDelegate {}

func didPressOptionButton(myAnswer: String) {
        if question1.myAnswers.contains(myAnswer) {
            if let firstIndex = question1.myAnswers.firstIndex(where: {$0 == myAnswer}) {
                question1.myAnswers.remove(at: firstIndex)
            }
        }else {
            question1.myAnswers.append(myAnswer)
        }
        self.answerView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: For more please get source from here. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H5YF-dKYq2fFwY4FfYMYw-QZCZp3AQ38?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put all of your answer buttons in a list. Then, inside `checkAnswerButtonTapped` you can run through the list and see which ones of them have `isSelected` set to true.

```
for button in buttonList {
     var answersSelected = []
     if button.isSelected {
          answersSelected.append(button.text) 
          // You may want something different here depending on how the buttons store the answer options
     }
}
```

Once you're done with that, compare them with the predefined correct answers from your `QuizManager`.

One other thing you could do to make your life a little bit easier is using the  `.toggle()` function with your Boolean variables. Basically it just switches the value of your variable. So in your `checkMarkAnswerClicked` you could just have `sender.isSelected.toggle()`

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
So, you mean that I could create a tableView an put all the Buttons in it?

Comment: You can put them in a table view if you would like, but what I was saying is a list like this:
`var answerButtons = [answerButton1, answerButton2, answerButton3]`

Comment: Ah ok you mean a Array? I tried it but its not working. I got a response that there ist no answerButton1 in Scope. Same for the rest. Sorry I think im stupid for coding -.-

Comment: Yes, an array! Lists and arrays refer to the same thing. Would you mind sharing some more of your code? How are you putting the buttons in the array?